# Google Flights - What programming language is used in the Google Flights /ITA Software - QPX etc

Tags: google-search

I am trying to find out which Prog. language or Technology goes into the working of Google Flights or the ITA matrix solutions like QPX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about web application development, not travel.

Comment: Maybe one of the programming groups, or even the database guys might be a better fit?

Comment: In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbdXeRBbgDM&t=13m55s) video titled *2018 LLVM Developers’ Meeting: C. Schafmeister "Lessons Learned Implementing Common Lisp with LLVM"* the speaker says of the programming language *common lisp* "google flights ... had been written in it".

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about reading  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITA_Software) ?

> ITA is also one of the highest-profile companies to base their software on Common Lisp

Once you know the magic word "lisp" and you know "qpx", the world (or rather Google) is your oyster. Here's a couple things I found for you:

Another [source](https://leanpub.com/lisphackers/read) claims

> ITA Software, one of the largest employers of lispers

From [an email Carl de Marcken of ITA Software sent to a friend in 2001](http://www.paulgraham.com/carl.html):

> The vast majority of our "thinking" code is in Common Lisp. We run both CMUCL and Franz
>
> we use C++ code to memory-map huge files containing pointerless C structs (of flights, fares, etc), and then access these from Common Lisp using foreign data accesses

Later a semi official [Common Lisp Survey](https://common-lisp.net/%7Edlw/LispSurvey-old.html) mentions that QPX uses Steel Bank CL (SBCL) which was forked from CMU CL in December, 1999 so at one point they switched from CMUCL to SBCL. It's not clear whether they still run Allegro. At least in 2013 we can find [mentions](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/mailman/message/31040338/) about how ITA QPX now at Google wants to speed up SBCL so they are certainly were using it at that point.

According to this [post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=911985) when they started working on Polaris (which Air Canada picked up and then dropped so I am not sure what came out of it) they also used a Lisp, albeit a different one.